# Code error- Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, module

I pip install requests module and bs4 module. In C drive i can see the installed modules:

[image]

and this is the sys.path of the added modules:

[image]

When i check all sys.path with:

```
import sys
for i in sys.path:
    print i
```

UPTADE
i get this list:

```
C:\Python27new\Lib\site-packages
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcToolBox\Scripts
```

But when i try to import requests and bs4 modules i get an error:

```
>>> import requests

  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
   import requests
  ImportError: No module named requests
```

and the same for bs4 module:

```
ImportError: No module named bs4
```

Answer (score 0):

If the picture is a listing of `C:\Python27new\Lib\site-packages` then you want that in your path, not `C:\Python27new\Lib\site-packages\requests`.

Comment: HI RENEMILK I UPDTAE THE RESULT

Comment: Is the first picture you posted of `C:\Python27new\Lib\site-packages` or of `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages`?

Comment: C:\Python27new\Lib\site-packages   ,thanks for the help-i need help urgent!!

Comment: Well, then you obviously haven't added the right path (`C:\Python27new\Lib\site-packages`) to your sys.path, like I said.

Comment: now i get the right path-thanks. but when i run code with module requests i get error that there is no requests module!! i don't understand it